# Why do images that refer to static nuxt assets that don't exist not trigger @error?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I have a nuxt application, and in it, I have an image tag where the source attribute refers to a nuxt static asset.

```
 <img
      class="player-face"
      :src="`/players/face/${player.name}.png`"
      @error="myFunction"
 />
```

If the image exists, it works as expected. If the image does not exist, I get a 404, which should trigger my @error handler, but it doesn't. It seems the problem is the fact that it's pointing to a nuxt static asset, because if I change the src to be `:src="'foo'"`, it triggers the error handler as expected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is caused by nuxt returning a 1x1 pixel image, which means the error handler is not fired (even though the 1x1 image is returned with a 404).

To stop nuxt returning this placeholder image, add the following to your `nuxt.config.js`

```
render: { fallback: false }
```

Comment: This didn't work for me, do you have any other suggestions? Nuxt v2.14.1

Answer (score 1):

When you use dynamic images like in your case with `` :src="`/players/face/${player.name}.png`" `` you have to store them in `assets` so that webpack can process them, not in the static folder.

Move them to the assets folder and update your links to:
`` :src="`~/assets/players/face/${player.name}.png`" ``